# Implementing try (look-ahead) and untilStop with parser combinators

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, alternative-functor

I am following [this tutorial](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html) for implementing Parser Combinators (a la parsec) in Haskell. I implemented everything of the NanoParsec mentioned throught this post.

For some hours now, I am struggeling to implement

```
-- try p. If p fails continue without consuming anything
try :: Parser a -> Parser a
try p = ...

-- Parser for everything, until the character-sequence stop appears. 
-- If stop does not appear at all: fail
untilStop :: String -> Parser String
untilStop stop = ...
```

My best attempt to implement `untilStop` looks like somewhat like this and does not quite work

```
untilStop :: String -> Parser String
untilStop (c : cs) = do
  s <- some $ satisfy (/= d)
  string (c : cs) <|> do
    i <- item
    untilStop (d : ds)
  -- maybe use msum from MonadPlus to combine?
```

I could not figure out how to combine `s`, `i` and the recursive call without failing everthing because of `string` are not getting everything together.

I think once I have `try`, `untilStop` should be straightforward. Can someone point me in the right direction or implement it (`try`) for me?

Right now I am still learning about Monads, Applicative and related stuff so trying to understand the sourcecode of parsec was impossible for me.

Comment: You don't need `try` for this simple parser library. `p <|> q` already behaves like `try p <|> q`. Am I right?

Comment: Well `<|> :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a` needs an alternative to my *tried* option. I was hoping for something I can just `try` and if it fails, do nothing and just move onto the next statement in my `do` notation.

Comment: That's exactly how `<|>` works already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I think you don't need to have a Parsec-like `try`.

For the `untilStop`, check this:

```
untilStop :: String -> Parser String
untilStop [] = everything
untilStop (c:cs) = item >>= fun
  where fun i = do { s <- untilStop cs;
                     if i == c && s == "" then return "" else failure } <|> do
                     s <- untilStop (c : cs)
                     return (i : s)
```

First, if the stop string is empty, you parse everything.  Where `everything` is:

```
everything :: Parser String
everything = Parser (\inp -> [(inp,"")])
```

Otherwise, if it is of the form `c:cs`, then parse a character `i` and consider two cases:

- The stop string is right in the front of the parsing stream (because `c == i` and parsing with the rest of the string `cs` gives an empty result), then return "". Or,
- It is somewhere in the stream, so you look for it further.

Note that the `<|>` operator is used to backtrack. If `untilStop cs` fails to be what we want, we need to *reparse*, using `untilStop (c:cs)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not work correctly. `parse (untilStop "end") "abcdef end"` gives `[("abcd", "ef end")]`.  It also does not really use the combinators which I think should be the goal.

Comment: Thanks **a lot**, that works in theory, but I suggested an edit to your solution to make it compile and copy-pastable. Formatting and such